# How to have selectableItemBackground on Imageview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a RecyclerView with each item having the "selectableItemBackground" enabled on the item layout to give me that ripple effect on touch. The problem is, the items have an imageView on them and the ripple effect only takes place under the image. How to have the ripple appear on the complete item layout (over the imageView as well), just like when touching on the items on Google Playstore?

Comment: You should apply the same to your item layout as background. You may share your layout.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alternatively you can try this:-
Simply, Wrap your ImageView with `CardView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I tried this, the selectableItemBackground didn't take effect on touch. Basically nothing happens.

Comment: I've edited the code :) Add `android:clickable="true"` into `cardView`.

Comment: lovely this worked. Except you needed to as focusable to true.

Comment: @SeargantPeauts Accept the answer at least.

Comment: I thought I did. Sorry. But yep, what about LinearLayout?

Comment: @SergeantPeauts I didn't get you.

Comment: The card view was not necessary for me. I just added a foreground attribute on the parent and that did the trick. thanks.

Comment: @peshkira that only works if your parent was a FrameLayout, for api < 23, `foreground` did not exist in View prior to 23, don't believe the docs https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37061503

Answer (score 5):

I solved set in parent content in `foreground` propiety value `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` and focusable enabled.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:focusable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cover_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_empty"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/default_image" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nice, using foreground you can even add a different background and the "press" effect still remain! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Inserting a `View` to other `ViewGroup` is affecting app performance, so you can just change your `ImageView` to `ImageButton` and give it `?attr/selectableItemBackground` as background

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_white" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"`in your RecyclerView in XML file.
And set Ripple effect selector as `android:background` property of you RecyclerView **cell**.

Example of selector for cell in drawable-v21 folder:

**ripple_selector.xml**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/preference_item_pressed"> <!-- ripple color -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </item> <!-- normal color -->
</ripple>
```

And example of cell with selector background:

**cell.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="72dp" android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_selector">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It still comes under the imageView of the cell.

Comment: Did you add `android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"` to your parent layout?

Comment: This was actually good. But it would only work for api 21 and above yeah?

Comment: Yes. You can use Ripple effect only from api 21. But you can use some libraries that allow you to make ripple in pre-Lollipop versions. Try https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect